# gimp scheme formatting result with leading zeroes

Tags: scheme, gimp, script-fu

I'm trying to get timestamp for filename.
I use procedure (time) which gives current timestamp:

```
(120 11 29 17 32 25)
```

year-1900 month-1 day hour minute second

```
(+ 1900 (car (time)) )(+ 1 (cadr (time)))(caddr(time))(cadddr(time))(cadr(cdddr(time)))(caddr(cdddr(time)))
```

this is almost good but... if any of element is lesser then 10 (e.g. first of january about 1 a.m.:

```
(121 0 1 1 2 3)
```

it gaves incorrect timestamp, because I need leading zeroes

`202111123` should be `20210101010203`

I wonder if there's a simplier method than checking the length of element and adding "0"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Script-Fu is based on [Tiny Scheme](http://tinyscheme.sourceforge.net/home.html), which is itself a subset of [R5RS Scheme](https://schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/). There is no built-in functionality in R5RS Scheme to format numbers or strings like this, and none added to Script-Fu as far as I know, so you will need to create your own functions for this.

It would be easiest to work with strings, and you probably want strings anyway for adding a timestamp to a filename.

Here is a function that left-pads a string with zeroes. Note that the result is at least `width` characters in length, but the input `str` is not trimmed if it is already longer than `width`:

```
(define (left-pad str width pad)
  (let add-padding ((s str))
    (if (< (- width (string-length s)) 1)
        s
        (add-padding (string-append pad s)))))
```

You can use this function in a `time-stamp` function that returns a string in the desired format:

```
(define (time-stamp)
  (let* ((curr (time))
         (year (number->string (+ 1900 (list-ref curr 0))))
         (month (left-pad (number->string (+ 1 (list-ref curr 1))) 2 "0"))
         (day (left-pad (number->string (list-ref curr 2)) 2 "0"))
         (hour (left-pad (number->string (list-ref curr 3)) 2 "0"))
         (minute (left-pad (number->string (list-ref curr 4)) 2 "0"))
         (second (left-pad (number->string (list-ref curr 5)) 2 "0")))
    (string-append year month day hour minute second)))
```

Here, `list-ref` is used instead of `cadr`, `caddr`, `cadddr`, etc.; this is easier to read and less error-prone. Note that [`list-ref`](https://schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-9.html#%_idx_426) uses zero-based indices into a list.

Then just call `time-stamp` to get a string containing the current time-stamp information. You can use `string->number` if you really want a number from this, either calling on the result of `time-stamp`, or calling `string->number` in the definition of `time-stamp` before the result is returned:

```
> (time-stamp)
"20201229133118"
> (string->number (time-stamp))
20201229133150
```

I ran the above test in GIMP, so it is showing my system time at that moment. Here is an example using your mock test:

```
> (define (time) '(121 0 1 1 2 3))
> (time-stamp)
"20210101010203"
> (string->number (time-stamp))
20210101010203
```

There is a lot of code duplication in the first version of `time-stamp` above. That version may look more obvious to someone not familiar with Scheme programming idioms, but here is a version in a more functional style that removes a lot of that code duplication:

```
(define (time-stamp)
  (let* ((curr (time))
         (y (+ 1900 (car curr)))
         (m (+ 1 (cadr curr)))
         (tstamp-nums (apply list y m (cddr curr))))
    (apply string-append
           (map (lambda (x) (left-pad (number->string x) 2 "0"))
                tstamp-nums))))
```

Comment: wow. I'm total beginner of TinyScheme, i just tried to adopt some script for my purposes. And didn't know the list-ref and made it with car(cdddr( and with if. But your solution is absolutely perfect... Great job!

Answer (score 1):

Finally I did this with that:

```
  (define year (+ 1900 (car (time))))
  (define month (+ 1 (cadr (time))))
  (define day (caddr(time)))
  (define hour (cadddr(time)))
  (define minute (cadr(cdddr(time))))
  (define second (caddr(cdddr(time))))

  (set! newFileName (string-append inDir pathchar inFileName
        (number->string year)
        (if (< month 10) (string-append "0" (number->string month)) (number->string month))
        (if (< day 10) (string-append "0" (number->string day)) (number->string day))
        (if (< hour 10) (string-append "0" (number->string hour)) (number->string hour))
        (if (< minute 10) (string-append "0" (number->string minute)) (number->string minute))
        (if (< second 10) (string-append "0" (number->string second)) (number->string second))
             saveString))
```

But I think that @ad absurdum answer is much better.